# Convert two columns Pandas data frame to dictionary of list with first column as keys

Tags: python, dictionary, pandas

I have the following data frame:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    "ClusterID" : [1,2,2,1,3],
    "Genes" : ['foo','qux','bar','cux','fii'],
})
```

Which looks like this:

```
  ClusterID Genes
0          1   foo
1          2   qux
2          2   bar
3          1   cux
4          3   fii
```

What I want to do is to convert them into a dictionary of list:

```
{ '1': ['foo','cux'],
  '2': ['qux','bar'],
  '3': ['fii']}
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and [`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html) [`tolist`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.tolist.html) and then use [`Series.to_dict`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.to_dict.html):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    "ClusterID" : [1,2,2,1,3],
    "Genes" : ['foo','qux','bar','cux','fii'],
})
print df
   ClusterID Genes
0          1   foo
1          2   qux
2          2   bar
3          1   cux
4          3   fii

s = df.groupby('ClusterID')['Genes'].apply(lambda x: x.tolist())
print s
ClusterID
1    [foo, cux]
2    [qux, bar]
3         [fii]
Name: Genes, dtype: object

print s.to_dict()
{1: ['foo', 'cux'], 2: ['qux', 'bar'], 3: ['fii']}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
dct = {x:df.Genes[df.ClusterID == x].tolist() for x in set(df.ClusterID)}
# dct == {1: ['foo','cux'], 2: ['qux','bar'], 3: ['fii']}
```

As your **ClusterID** column consists of integer values, your dictionary keys will be as well.  If you want the keys to be strings as in your example, simply use the `str` function as

```
dct = {str(x):df.Genes[df.ClusterID == x].tolist() for x in set(df.ClusterID)}
```

Here we are using a dictionary comprehension statement.  The expression `set(df.ClusterID)` will get us a set of the unique values in that column (we can use a set as the dictionary keys are unordered anyways).  `df.Genes[df.ClusterID == x]` will get us the values in the **Genes** column corresponding to the rows with the **ClusterID** values equal to x.  Using `tolist()` will cast the pandas.Series returned there to a list.

Thus this dictionary expression loops through each unique value in the **ClusterID** column, and stores the list of **Genes** values corresponding to that value as a list in a dictionary under that key.