# Vectorized solution to conditional dataframe selection

Tags: python, pandas, conditional-statements, vectorization

I recently asked a question which was answered -  [How do I add conditionally to a selection of cells in a pandas dataframe column when the the column is a series of lists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35222716/how-do-i-add-conditionally-to-a-selection-of-cells-in-a-pandas-dataframe-column), but I believe have a new problem which I had not previously considered.

In the following dataframe I need two conditions to result in a change to column `d`. Each value in column `d` is a `list`.

- Where `a == b`, the final integer in d is incremented by one.
- Where `a != b`, the list of integers is extended and the value `1` is inserted at the end of the `list` in column `d`.

  ```
  a       b       c           d           
  On      On      [0]         [0,3]       
  On      Off     [0]         [0,1]
  On      On      [0]         [2]         
  On      On      [0]         [0,4,4]         
  On      Off     [0]         [0]
  ```
- As a result, the dataframe would like this:

  ```
  a       b       c       d       
  On      On      [0]     [0,4]       
  On      Off     [0]     [0,1,1]     
  On      On      [0]     [3]
  On      On      [0]     [0,4,5] 
  On      Off     [0]     [0,1]
  ```

I realise that this can be done using `pd.Series.apply` method in conjunction with a predefined function or use of `lambda` however the data frame consists of 100000 rows and I was hoping that a vectorized solution to these two conditions may exist.

Comment: Storing non-scalar values as data elements is ill-advised and typically you lose access to vectorised methods as np and pandas has no vectorised methods for appending to a list in a vectorised manner

Comment: I had a feeling that might be the case. As a new user of pandas what is a more typical way of capturing this data? The data frame has approximately half a million updates to run through each time with differing results in col `a` and col `b`. If `a == b` then the count increases and if `a != b` a new count needs to be started.

Answer (score 0):

As Edchum [says](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35287780/vectorized-solution-to-conditional-dataframe-selection#comment58286228_35287780), vecorised solution can be problematic.

One non vectorized solution with [`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.apply.html) custom `functions`:

```
df['e'] = df['d']

def exten(lst):
    return lst + [1]

def incre(lst):
    lst[-1] = lst[-1] + 1
    return lst

df.loc[df.a != df.b, 'd'] = df.e.apply(exten)
df.loc[df.a == df.b, 'd'] = df.e.apply(incre)
df = df.drop('e', axis=1)
print df
    a    b    c          d
0  On   On  [0]     [0, 4]
1  On  Off  [0]  [0, 1, 1]
2  On   On  [0]        [3]
3  On   On  [0]  [0, 4, 5]
4  On  Off  [0]     [0, 1]
```

Comment: Hi, much appreciated. This is pretty much exactly what I am currently using (although your functions are more elegant!) but because of the row count its taking a bit too long for its intended use.

Comment: Yes, I try to find better solution. But question is: column `c` is `list` of length `1`?

Comment: Sorry, but my vectorized approach was more slowly as this answer. Maybe you can try do not use `lists` in columns `c` and `d` if is not neccessary. You can check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35287398/2901002) for converting `lists` to `column`. And [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35030384/2901002) for converting to `lists`, if it is neccessary.