# Creating pandas data frame with index with values in different sizes

Tags: python, pandas

is it possible to do the following (dict is data for the first row index):

```
dict={'col1':1,'col2':[1,2],'col3':'str'}

nm=pd.DataFrame(dict,index=['new line'])
```

I expect to receive a data frame looking like:

```
nm

          col1   col2 col3

new line     1  [1,2]  str
```

with the values in col2 of type list, but instead I receive the following error:

> ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (2) into shape
>   (1)

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are miss one `[]`:

```
dict={'col1':1,'col2':[[1,2]],'col3':'str'} 
nm=pd.DataFrame(dict,index=['new line'])

print nm
          col1    col2 col3
new line     1  [1, 2]  str
```

Or:

```
dict={'col1':[1],'col2':[[1,2]],'col3':['str']} 
nm=pd.DataFrame(dict,index=['new line'])

print nm
          col1    col2 col3
new line     1  [1, 2]  str
```

If you have more values, you need use list to each column as `Series`, so if you need `list` in column, you have to use `list` of `lists`:

```
dict={'col1':[1, 2],'col2':[[1,2], [3,5]],'col3':['str', 'str1']} 
nm=pd.DataFrame(dict,index=['new line', 'new line1'])

print nm
           col1    col2  col3
new line      1  [1, 2]   str
new line1     2  [3, 5]  str1
```

Storing non-scalar values as data elements is ill-advised and typically you lose access to vectorised methods as `np` and `pandas` has no vectorised methods for appending to a `list` in a vectorised manner. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35287780/vectorized-solution-to-conditional-dataframe-selection/35288742#comment58286228_35287780)